# Pronunciación de la letra ge

Tags: diferencias-regionales, pronunciación

En un curso de `Memrise.com` hay extractos donde la ge en "amigo" y "lugar" se pronuncia como una leve jota, casi como una hache.

¿Es realmente la pronunciación castellana?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, tal como dice la RAE:

> 1. f. Séptima letra del abecedario latino internacional y octava del español, que representa, ante las vocales e, i, un fonema consonántico fricativo, velar y sordo, y en los demás casos un fonema consonántico velar y sonoro. Su nombre es ge.
>
>    ORTOGR. Para representar el fonema velar y sonoro ante e, i, se escribe una u interpuesta, que no se pronuncia; p. ej., en guedeja, guisa. En los casos en que la u se pronuncia en alguna de estas combinaciones, debe llevar diéresis; p. ej., en Sigüenza, argüir.

Por lo tanto para los casos específicos que mencionas como "amigo" o "lugar" sería el fonema velar y sonoro, mismo usado en palabras como "gato" o "gorila".

Comment: Sería el mismo fonema, pero no necesariamente el mismo fono.

Answer (score 2):

La letra G en "amigo" y "lugar" tiene un pronunciación leve (a diferencia de "gestar" o "gestionar" que tienen una pronunciación parecida a la letra J, siendo comunes los casos en que esto sucede, pero mayormente se la encuentra de forma 'leve' como mencioné previamente).

En este caso la letra G en "amigo" y "lugar" suena igual o muy parecido a la G en las palabras inglesas "good", "God", "ongoing", "organization", entre otras.

Comment: Parecido, quizás. Igual, no. En "amigo" y "lugar", la /g/ (usualmente) se pronuncia como un aproximante.

Answer (score 1):

http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonolog%C3%ADa_del_espa%C3%B1ol#Sonidos_conson.C3.A1nticos

> /b/, /d/, y /g/ son aproximantes ([β̞], [ð̞], [ɣ˕]; (de aquí en adelante representado sin tachuelas) en todas las posiciones excepto después de pausa, después de consonante nasal, o, en el caso de /d/, después de consonante lateral; en estos contextos, son oclusivas sonoras

¿Podría ser esto lo que has oído? En "amigo" y "lugar" usualmente /g/ no se pronuncia como la /g/ en inglés.